# I can't re-reference a TableRow with findViewById

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an activity where I create Tablerow programatically, as I don't know how many files I need.
Each TableRow has an ID starting by 100 and continue 200, 300 and so on.
When I create the row 3 the TableRow's ID is 300.
Then when someone edit other row I need to know what row is just to work with the elements of the row.

My problem: previous value:
trActiva.getId()=300

Then this is my code I put:

```
 lineaActiva = (tv.getId()) / 100 * 100;
 trActiva = findViewById(lineaActiva);
```

just on the point before these two lines trActiva.getId()=300
after the first row of the code lineaActiva = 200
That means after the second line trActiva.getId() should be 200 but it is still 300.

More weird things:
after these two lines:

```
trActiva.getId()=300
findViewById(lineaActiva).getId()=200
```

What is happening here? Why trActiva is not changing?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

We are unsure how you are increasing your Id and how you are storing your data as well how do you view 300 rows on a computer screen
So a lot of code is missing to give a very pointed answer to your question
Here is a table we populate from a Derby Database
The table is named ptable and we might also mention we are using a Model View Controller pattern to manage the data to GET and SET variables
First we read from the Database and populate the ptable with this code

```
private void ReadFromParent() throws SQLException{

ObservableList<ParentModel> TableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    stmnt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Parent"); 
    while (rs.next()){// Add data to observableArrayList TableData to select a table ROW

    TableData.add(new ParentModel(rs.getString("PID"),rs.getString("pMonth"),rs.getString("pYear")));
    }
    PropertyValueFactory<ParentModel, String> IDCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("PID");
    colID.setCellValueFactory(IDCellValueFactory);
    PropertyValueFactory<ParentModel, String> DateCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("pMonth");
    colMonth.setCellValueFactory(DateCellValueFactory);
    PropertyValueFactory<ParentModel, String> TypeCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("pYear");
    colYear.setCellValueFactory(TypeCellValueFactory);

    // ================================================================
    // colTxDate are the ID's for the tableview columns
    // sortDate  are the Column Names for the Database TABLE CDBalance
    // ================================================================
    colMonth.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
    colYear.setStyle("-fx-alignment:CENTER;");

    Collections.sort(TableData, (p2, p1)-> p1.getPID().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getPID()));
    // Line of Code above Sorts Database Columns based on VARIABLE in ParentModel
    // Change p2,p1 to sort Ascending or Descending
    if(TableData.size() < 15) {// Format TableView to display Vertical ScrollBar
        ptable.setPrefWidth(336);// 19 is the off set
    }else {
        ptable.setPrefWidth(355);
    }   ptable.setItems(TableData);
    stmnt.close();  
}
```

Then we write listener code to permit us to view the details of the row selected
Notice we get the ID from the row selected
This is where you can use that value to find the new entry that is greater than 300
OR you can write a Search query on the table that finds all records that have an ID greater than 300

Here is the code that permits you to click on a row in the table

```
    private void showTableDataDetails(ParentModel info) throws IOException{
    if (info != null) {
        info =  (ParentModel) ptable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        strID = info.getPID();
        strMONTH = info.getPMonth();
        strYEAR = info.getPYear();
        toChildView();
        System.out.println("########### PID "+strID);
    } 
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    ptable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends ParentModel>
        observable,ParentModel oldValue, ParentModel newValue) -> {
        try {
            showTableDataDetails((ParentModel) newValue); // When a row of the table is Selected call
            // Proper Construction                       // showTableDataDetails method
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ParentTableViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps and Welcome to Stack Overflow
PLEASE post a little more code in the future so your question can have a more definitive answer